# Telnet: Network is unreachable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, port, telnet

I'm new with Ruby on Rails, so I was trying to figure out how to send emails from the server.
I have followed several tutorial without success, so decided to check the basics and see if port 25 is open, I get the following line:

```
$ telnet example.com 25
Trying 93.184.216.34...
Trying 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

I have read about `Conection refused` but I can't figure out about `unreachable` is my port blocked or maybe my ISP?

Any help is useful

Comment: Looks as though you're trying to telnet to `example.com` port 25. If you want to check if port 25 is open from your server. Then you should try your servers DNS instead of example.com :)

Answer (score 0):

if you using ubuntu / debian based

### check your server firewall and allow port 25

- sudo ufw allow 25/tcp

### 1. install  [postfix](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) if you want to build your own smtp server

### 2. other Alternatif

- using gmail account as smtp server in rails , [action mailer with gmail as smtp](https://launchschool.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails)
- or you can register to sendgrid.com as smtp server (not free but can apply testing account for one year trial)